# Nuxt deployment

Tags: express, deployment, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))
    //handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req,res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/app.template.html')) //refers to any route
}
```

what page / file do I serve `app.get(/.*/, (req,res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/app.template.html'))` here that will mean that when I localy / when I deploy my app it will run my nuxt app?

The app uses nuxt3 express node and axios, I have got it running perfectly on a dev server but deployment is causing a lot of problems since I can't find many solutions that I can understand. I was planning on deploying on vercel since its free but I was also considering heroku.

the screen shot is the public files
[image: public file structure]

github link to the repo: https://github.com/Duckjpeg/dsad

Comment: Why do you need an Express server here? What is your use-case? Also, why are you not following the Nuxt structure? You need an express app or a Nuxt one?

Comment: The express server handles requests from the nuxt front end and handles all requests and responses and the nuxt is for the front end, I didn’t realise nuxt could work as a full stack. The use case is a todo list app with authentication (mainly as a project for fun/ to learn)